# Creating an IAM role that has a trust relationship with another account

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have 2 AWS accounts, Account#1 and Account#2.

In Account#2, I am creating a role that has a trust relationship with Account#1 like:

```
"Statement" : [
    "Sid" : "",
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Principal" : {
       "AWS" : "arn:aws:iam::123:root"
    },
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
]
```

When doing this, doesn't Account#1 have to somehow allow Account#2 to create this trust relationship?  If yes, where does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to Switch Role from one account to the other. The "receiving account" doesn't need to know about this but you, as a user, definitely do.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-console.html